# Promise not giving stacktrace

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am new to promises and am probably doing something wrong. I am making a backup of a MongoDB instance using Mongodump. Everything works fine, however I got a slight problem with the stacktrace. In a function, that should be awaited using async/await in the main process I am creating a new promise. At the end of the function I am calling (Cut out the beginning):

```
backupDB(collection) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let backupLog = [];
        backupLog.push({
            time: moment(),
            msg: `Backup for ${collection} started`
        });            

        let spawnArguments = [
            '--host', 'localhost',
            '--port', portProd,
            '--collection', collection,
            '--db', dbNameProd,
            '--out', dumpPath
        ];

        const spawnprocess = spawn(mongodumpPath, spawnArguments,
            {shell: true}
        );

        spawnprocess.on('close', (code) => {
            if (code === 0) {
                backupLog.push({
                    time: moment(),
                    msg: `Backup for ${collection} finished`
                });                
                resolve(backupLog);
            } else {
                backupLog.push({
                    time: moment(),
                    msg: `Backup for ${collection} failed`
                }); 
                reject(backupLog);
            }
        });
```

The variable mongodumpPath is deliberately not defined (for the sake of demonstraion), but when I run the function inside a try catch, no error is thrown:

```
    try {
        log = log.concat(await this.backupDB('ops', {regDate: {$gte: {$date: fromDate}, $lte: {$date: toDate}}})); 

    } catch (e) {
        log = log.concat(e);
        return log;
    }
```

If I call

```
this.backupDB('ops', {regDate: {$gte: {$date: fromDate}, $lte: {$date: toDate}}})
```

a stacktrace is thrown in the console. I guess this is due to me only rejecting the error, when spawnprocess is emitting a close event. The program crashes before though, so how can I catch that?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this via the following catch:

```
        if (e.stack) {
            log.push({
                time: moment(),
                msg: e.stack
            });
        } else {
            log = log.concat(e);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with promises, if the function you are calling returns a promise, you should be able to append a `.catch` to the function calls to handle a reject.

with your code it would look something like :

```
let backupCall = await this.backupDB('ops', {regDate: {$gte: {$date: fromDate}, $lte: {$date: toDate}}})).catch((error) => console.log(error));
log = log.concat(backupCall)
```

notice the `catch` appended to the this.backupDB call line

Comment: Shouldn't this already be handled by the try/catch block (see above)

Comment: @rStorms That doesn't necessarily make this answer wrong... a try catch block works as well, however since the only logic in the try catch block is the one async call, tacking on the .catch makes for cleaner code.  The try/ catch block would be more practical if you have multiple calls / statements in the try block where things can go wrong and you would want to catch any of those errors.  In this scenario the `.catch` should generally be used since we are only looking for an error thrown by that one function.

Comment: Totally ok, I didnt downvote this ;) However doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Yeah sorry, that's my fault I missed some of that.  To answer your problem, I could be wrong but log.concat could be somehow be getting in between your error and handling it (not throwing the error inside of that), the answer I posted doesn't catch your error prior to the log?